# Making video background height responsive

Tags: html, css

See here - https://harrigreeves.me

I have my video and it's container inside a section at the top of an HTML page -

```
<section id="intro">   

    <div class="intro-overlay">
        <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
            <source src="background.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>  

    <div class="intro-content">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-twelve">

                <h1>Harri Greeves</h1>

                <h2 class="intro-position">Front-end Web Developer</h2>

                <a href="#" title="Download CV" class="button button-primary">Download CV</a>

            </div>  
            
        </div>                  
    </div> <!-- /intro-content --> 

    <ul class="intro-social">
         <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/harrigreeves/"><i class="fa fa-linkedin slideup"></i></a></li>
         <li><a target="_blank" href="https://github.com/greevesh"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></a></li>       
      </ul> <!-- /intro-social -->          

   </section> <!-- /intro -->
```

Basically, I want the height of the video background to still take up the entire viewport when the screen scales down in size.

Right now you, can see a dark grey space underneath the video background.

```
#intro {
    background-image: url(../background.mp4);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    min-height: 720px;
    display: table;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    background-size: 750px;
}
.intro-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    opacity: .85;
}
```

I thought if I the video background was given a 100vh it would be fully responsive. How come this isn't the case and what else do I need to add/remove to make it so?

Answer (score 0):

Add this class on your video tag:

```
.hero-video{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    object-fit: cover;
    inset: 0;
}
```